# DocumentDB LINQ Query - Select method not supported

Tags: join, lambda, azure-cosmosdb

**The Application:**

- .Net Standard Class Library (Containing a series of Repositories)
- Latest version https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core
- Azure Cosmos DB Emulator

**Sample Document Structure:**

```js
{
 "ProfileName": "User Profile 123",
 "Country": "UK",
 "Tags": [{
  "Id": "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597263",
  "Name": "Tag 1"
 },
 {
  "Id": "caa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20",
  "Name": "Tag 2"
 }],
 "Topics": [{
  "Id": "baa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20",
  "Name": "Topic A"
 },
 {
  "Id": "aaa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc30",
  "Name": "Topic B"
 },
 {
  "Id": "eaa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc40",
  "Name": "Topic C"
 }]
}
```

**The Problem:**
The issue I have is that any LINQ query I execute that contains a .Select, returns an error stating that the Select method is not supported.

**What I Need?**
I want to be able to use a LINQ Expression to return all documents WHERE:

1. Country = UK
2. Tags contains a specific GUID
3. Topics contain a specific GUID

Comment: so what is the query you ran

Comment: I want the LINQ query representation of the following SQL query:

SELECT c FROM profiles c
  join ct in c.Topics
  join l in c.Tags
WHERE c.Country= 'UK'
AND ct.id = 'fa2e11e3-07aa-450a-8fc0-da3c738fec98'
AND l.id = '260dadbc-d2de-457a-8d42-98799875b10f'

Answer (score 1):

> What I Need? I want to be able to use a LINQ Expression to return all documents

In your case, the Tags and Topic are object array, if you use the following linq code it will get **null**.

```
 var q = from d in client.CreateDocumentQuery<Profile>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("database", "coll"))
                where d.Country == "UK"  && d.Tags.Contains(new Tag
                {
                   Id = "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597264"
                }) && d.Topics.Contains(new Topic
                {
                    Id = "baa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc22"
                })
                select d;
```

I also try to override `IEqualityComparer` for Tag and Topic

```
public class CompareTag: IEqualityComparer<Tag>
    {


        public bool Equals(Tag x, Tag y)
        {
            return x != null && x.Id.Equals(y?.Id);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Tag obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And try it again then get **Contains** is **not supported** by Azure documentDb SDK

```
 var q = from d in client.CreateDocumentQuery<Profile>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("database", "coll"))
                where d.Country == "UK"  && d.Tags.Contains(new Tag
                {
                   Id = "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597264"
                },new CompareTag()) && d.Topics.Contains(new Topic
                {
                    Id = "baa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc22"
                }, new CompareTopic())
                    select d;
```

**My workaround** is that we could use the SQL query directly. It works correctly on my side. We also could test it on the Azure portal.

```
SELECT * FROM root WHERE (ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.Tags, {"Id": "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597263"}, true) And ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.Topics, {"Id": "baa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20"}, true) And root.Country = 'UK' )
```

[image]

Query with SDK

```
  FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };
  var endpointUrl = "https://cosmosaccountName.documents.azure.com:443/";
  var primaryKey = "VNMIT4ydeC.....";
  var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), primaryKey);
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM root WHERE (ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.Tags, {\"Id\":\"686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597263\"},true) AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.Topics, {\"Id\":\"baa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20\"},true) AND root.Country  = \"UK\")";
  var profileQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Profile>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("dbname", "collectionName"),sql, queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

  var profileList = new List<Profile>();
   while (profileQuery.HasMoreResults)
   {
      profileList.AddRange(profileQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Profile>().Result);

   }
```

[image]

**Profile.cs file**

```
 public class Profile
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string ProfileName { get; set; }
        public Tag[] Tags{ get; set; }

        public Topic[] Topics { get; set; }

    }
```

**Topic.cs**

```
public class Topic
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

**Tag.cs**

```
public class Tag
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```